# If wine was used in a marinara sauce recipe, is this considered haram?

Tags: halal-haram, food, alcohol

If wine was used in a marinara sauce recipe, where it was essentially boiled off over a 5 hour period, is this still considered haram?

How about beer-battered fish? You couldn't eat enough of these foods in a sitting without dying before even catching a buzz.

Answer (score 2):

All perfect praise be to Allah.

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “Every body that is nourished with haraam things, the Fire is more
>   befitting for it.” Narrated by al-Tabaraani; classed as saheeh by
>   Shaykh al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Jaami’ (4519).

The Muslim should beware of eating that which is it not permissible for him to eat, and he should seek out halaal food, even if it is more expensive than other food, and even if obtaining it involves more effort.

From a proper fatwa [Here](https://islamqa.info/en/1814) on a similar question:

> It is not permissible to eat dishes cooked with alcohol, as ALL the
>   alcohol is not evaporated with cooking or heat. Refer to the
>   following, quoted from the famous Mayo Clinic:
>
> [Begin quote]
>
> Many people believe that because alcohol is sensitive to heat, it is
>   eliminated with cooking. However, not all the alcohol content of
>   alcoholic drinks is removed with heat; it depends on the type and time
>   of cooking. For instance if you add beer or wine to boiling liquid,
>   then immediately remove it from the heat, 85 per cent of the alcohol
>   content will remain. If you light the alcohol, as in flambé dishes, 75
>   per cent will remain. Even after simmering the dish for one and a half
>   hours, it will still have 20 per cent of the original alcohol content.
>
> It is only if you simmer the mixture for two or more hours, (as you
>   would with a wine-based beef casserole), that as little as five to 10
>   per cent of the original alcohol content remains.

Besides i don't get the point of adding wine or alcohol if you believe it will still evaporate 100%, there must have been some ingredients left. as stated [here](http://www.islamtomorrow.com/articles/alcohol_cooked.htm).

**Edit:** Today i found this hadees.

> **Narrated 'Aishah: That the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Every
>   intoxicant is unlawful. Whatever a Faraq of it intoxicates, then a
>   handful of it is unlawful."
>   [Abu 'Eisa said:] One of them said in his Hadith: "A sip of it is
>   unlawful."
>   He said: This Hadith is Hasan. Al-Laith bin Abi Sulaim and Ar-Rabi'
>   bin Sabih reported similar to the narration of Mahdi bin Maimun from
>   Abu 'Uthman Al-Ansari. Abu 'Uthman Al-Ansari's (a narrator in this
>   chain) name is 'Amr bin Salim, and they say: "Umar bin Salim" (as
>   well).** Book: The Book on Drinks - كتاب الأشربة عن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم
>   Global Id: 31939 (0) Grade: Hasan (Darussalam) Reference : Jami`
>   at-Tirmidhi 1866 In-book reference : Book 26, Hadith 6 English
>   translation : Vol. 3, Book 24, Hadith 1866

**Edit2:** This hadees tells how swear matter this is, and how much we need to be stay away from it, it is not just about intoxication of alcohol.

> Hadhrat Anas (Radi Allah Anho) says that the Holy prophet, Hadhrat
>   Muhammad-ur Rasullullaah (Sallallaahu Alayhi Wasallam) **cursed ten
>   people in connection with wine; the wine-presser, the one who has it
>   pressed, the one who drinks it, the one who conveys it, the one to
>   whom it is conveyed, the one who serves it, the one who sells it, the
>   one who benefits from the price paid for it, the one who buys it and
>   the one for whom it is bought.** (Al-Tirmidhi 2246).

**P:S:** I know some rulings/Fatwas in favor of eating such dishes. But they also state to be on safe side avoid this. I personally will avoid such foods to be on safe side.

And same i am advising to you as in a hadees it states:

> It was narrated on the authority of Yazeed Al-Qushayri that the Prophet, sallallaahu 'alayhi wa sallam, asked him: “Would you like [to enter] Paradise?”He replied,“Yes.”The Prophet,sallallaahu 'alayhi wa sallam, said:**“Then like for your brother what you like for yourself.”** [Ahmad]

As a rule of thumb, we should avoid such things about which we are not clear either they are halal or haram. As Allah says in quran:

> As for those in whose hearts is deviation [from truth], they will follow that of it which is unspecific, seeking discord and seeking an interpretation [suitable to them]. Quran/3/7

May Allah guide us all tot he right path.

Comment: @jason **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification to improve the post; they are *not* intended for argument and debate and especially not for proving or disproving controversial (and tangential) points.

Comment: Does this include Coke and/or Pepsi?

Comment: @daleyjem If it is intoxicant in large quantity, than yes. But i don't think it does so, but i have never tried or researched on it though.

Comment: The related question for Coke, etc., is: [Haraam or Halal? - Coke and Pepsi contain 0.001% Alcohol](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/3011/17163).