# Is Marmite Halal/Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, food

Marmite is made from leftover brewers yeast, it is popular in South Africa, Australia, etc.

> Marmite is made from yeast extract, a by-product of beer brewing. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marmite))

So would it be considered halal, or is it haram?

[image: Marmite; Image source Wikimedia Commons: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Marmite.jpg]

Comment: The answer is more or less simple if it contains alcohol or any thing which could be considered as intoxication it is clearly haram!

Answer (score 3):

Marmite is haram. Eat vegemite instead!

Kiwi-bashing aside, from their [FAQ](https://marmite.co.nz/faqs/):

> Is Marmite certified Halal?
>   Yes – The Halal Certification Authority
>   of Australia has certified Marmite as a Halal product.
>
> Is Marmite kosher certified?
>   Yes – Marmite is Kosher certified.
>
> Is Marmite suitable for vegans and vegetarians?
>   Yes – Marmite is
>   vegan and vegetarian friendly.

Answer (score 2):

This same problem arose in [Haraam or Halal? - Coke and Pepsi contain 0.001% Alcohol](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/3011/17163), where it was noted that e.g. Coke contains minute amounts of alcohol.  So I reiterate the main ideas of my answer in this context:

- If a substance is incapable of intoxicating even in large quantities, then it is not haram (insofar as to being an intoxicant; it could still be haram for other reasons).

  > Some people think that the words of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him), “Whatever intoxicates in large quantities, a little of it is haraam”, mean that if a small percentage of an intoxicant is mixed with a large amount of a substance that is not intoxicating, then it is haraam. This is a misunderstanding of the hadeeth. ... **if something is mixed with alcohol but the alcohol is a small amount and does not have any effect, then it is halaal and does not come under the ruling of this hadeeth.** -- [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/33763), in the context of non-alcoholic beers
- The prohibition applies to the substance as a whole, not to it's individualized parts:

  > Sheikh [Salman al-Oadah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salman_al-Ouda) astutely observed: "The percentage of alcohol mentioned has no effect on the ruling. **The ruling applies to the drink itself taken as a whole and not to its composition.**"  -- [IslamToday.net](http://en.islamtoday.net/artshow-409-3342.htm), also in the context of non-alcoholic beers

It's reasonable to believe that even a large amount of Marmite is incapable of intoxicating, and thus prohibition due to being an intoxicant does not apply.

Comment: Are you implicitly implying that drinking non-alcoholic beer is ok?

Comment: I'm not implying anything; I'm just relaying what the scholars have said.  The linked answer gives examples of fatawa which consider non-alcoholic beer as okay.  E.g. [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/33763) write: *The second type is beer that is not intoxicating, either because it is completely free of alcohol, or because it contains a minuscule amount of alcohol that does not reach the level of causing intoxication no matter how much a person drinks of it. The scholars have ruled that this is permissible*.

Answer (score -4):

Anything that can make you intoxicated is not good. The key point is effect of the substance not what it is made from.

Comment: A lot of additive that can causes cancers are considered halal. So, there are contradictions here in what you say.