# Is this hadith authentic? "Alcohol itself is prohibited and intoxication in every other beverage."

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity, alcohol

I saw this hadith quoted by [Mufti Ebrahim Desai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebrahim_Desai) in an AskImam.com fatwa [6408](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/6408.html):

> Furthermore, Rasulullah (Sallallaahu Álayhi Wasallam) said, 'Alcohol itself
>   is prohibited and intoxication in every other beverage.' (Hidaaya vol. 4 p.
>   497).

**Question**: Is this hadith authentic?

It probably is, since it was quoted in this fatwa.  It was also in two other AskImam.com fatawa by the same author ([10687](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/10687.html) and [6](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/6.html)) but the quotes are identical.

My Google-fu didn't help here.  I don't know what "Hidaaya" is, but if it's this http://www.alhidaaya.com/sw/, then it's not in English.  Google says it's [Swahili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swahili_language).

---

It's also available from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/16668) (and the other two mentioned are [here](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/16668) and [here](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/18934)).  This is the text of the fatwa:

> Category: Food
>
> Fatwa#: 6408
>
> Asked Country: Canada
>
> Answered Date: Aug 13, 2002
>
> **Title**: Are coke and soft drinks haraam or mushkook(doubtful)? Please reply!
>
> **Question**
>
> I recently received a copy of Mujlisul Ulama 25 page document in
>   english regarding their fatwa against comsumption of all coke and
>   carbonated drinks due to the syrups being extracted with alcholic
>   slovents. I read on your website other fatwas, but an still confused?
>   Is it mushkook, halaal, haraam? are you a part of this Mujlesul Ulama?
>   Do They have any email contact? I can also forward you the documents
>   via email if necessary.
>
> **Answer**
>
> Principally, if the alcohol is extracted from grapes or dates it is
>   not permissible. Rasulullah (Sallallaahu Álayhi Wasallam) said, ‘Khamr
>   (wine) is from these two trees, dates and grapes.’ (Mishkãt p. 317).
>
> Furthermore, Rasulullah (Sallallaahu Álayhi Wasallam) said, ‘Alcohol
>   itself is prohibited and intoxication in every other beverage.’
>   (Hidaaya vol. 4 p. 497).
>
> In view of the abovementioned Hadith, since the alcohol in coke is
>   from ethanol which is fermented from sugar cane mollasses and does not
>   intoxicate, it is permissible. However, if one is doubtful, he may
>   exercise precaution and abstain.
>
> and Allah Ta’ala Knows Best
>
> Mufti Ebrahim Desai

The hadith itself is copy/pasted all over the web: e.g. these forums [IslamicTeachings.org](http://www.islamicteachings.org/forum/topic/21741-wearing-makeuphairgel-etc-with-haram-or-impure-substances/); [SearchQuran.com](http://www.searchquran.com/showCat.php?mod=showDetails&qid=2253); [MuftiSays.com](http://www.muftisays.com/forums/82-the-food-section/7644-qasdus-sabeel-by-hazrat-maulana-thanvi-rh.html?p=48714); [PakLinks.com](http://www.paklinks.com/gs/archive/index.php/t-215667.html); [IslamicBoard.com](http://www.islamicboard.com/archive/index.php/t-134288833.html); [Islam.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35651/17163), but they are all almost identical.

(I ask because it arose for my answer to this question [Haraam or Halal? - Coke and Pepsi contain 0.001% Alcohol](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/3011/17163))

Comment: Hidayya means in Arabic guidance could you post some more relevant information maybe a narrator or so, unfortunately your fatwa is on a site my firewall blocks. It could be a casual reference to Hidayyat al-Hayran or any book as some books are known among people in short names like al-Ehya' which is Ehya' 'ulm ad-Dyn of al-Ghazaly who has also a book named bidayat al-Hidayya. I also found this reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Hidayah and  a book called al-Hidaya fi sharh bidayat al-Mubtadi الهداية في شرح بداية المبتدي of al-Murghini.

Comment: My first try and this was also quoted in "al-Hidaya fi sharh bidayat al-Mubtadi" is this hadith which you may find in many hadith collections http://sunnah.com/muslim/36/95

Comment: Possibly, but the Mufti uses it to imply coke is permissible, rather than forbidden, which the sunnah.com hadith would instead support (unless I'm misunderstanding it).

Comment: I've found it -at least I hope- and I'm trying to answer your question already!

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Ma sha Allah you are so eager to learn it is better and essential to learn from proper teachers and scholars rather internet otherwise one would always be confused here is the link you could choose  for free online courses from very respected scholars. http://courses.seekershub.org/

Comment: Al hidaya in fiqh is usually reffered to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Hidayah

Comment: @servant your link made me wonder, I just found out that the supposed "Arabic" translation of that link in Wikipedia refers to a Shi'a book. Interestingly the name of the book  الهداية في شرح بداية المبتدي is IMO confirming the fact that the riwaya of Hafs was not that common in earlier centuries as I quoted in my answer here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13195/why-is-the-hafs-reading-of-the-quran-so-prevalent/31179 when even a hanafi scholar doesn't put a hamza on المبتدي!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most authentic hadith including parts of your quote is [this](http://sunnah.com/muslim/36/95) from sahih Muslim which is quoted in "al-Hidayah fi takhriji ahadith al-Bidyah الهداية في تخريج أحاديث البداية" by the hafidh [Muhammad ibn as-Siddiq al-Ghomari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmad_al-Ghumari), as a mohaddith he commented or tried to authentify the ahadith from "bidayat al-Mujtahid wa nihayat al-Muqtasid بداية المجتهد ونهاية المقتصد" (also known as The Distinguished Jurist's Primer) of ibn Rushd (the grandson, also known as Averroes) which is a nice book on comparative fiqh.

But there are narrations of ibn 'Abbas in sunan an-Nasa'i which seem to cover your quote to some extent:

> "Khamr was forbidden in and of itself, in small or large amounts, as was every kind of intoxicating drink."

see for example in the book of drinks (51) "Chapter 48: Reports Used by Those Who Permit the Drinking of Intoxicants" the hadith [145](http://sunnah.com/nasai/51/145) (with the comment of an-Nasa'i that ibn Shubrumah didn't hear it from Abdullah ibn Shaddad), [146](http://sunnah.com/nasai/51/146), [147](http://sunnah.com/nasai/51/147) (comment of an-Nasa'i ibn al-Hakkam didn't mention the statement "in small or large amounts", so he seems to have different roots of this hadith) and [148](http://sunnah.com/nasai/51/148) (this apparently was the most preferred or authentic chain according an-Nasa'i's comments). Al-Bayhaqi (in his [as-sunan al-Kubra](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=673&pid=333261&hid=19293)-Arabic link only) also quoted this hadith with a partly similar chain as 148.

However the grading or qualification on sunnah.com says the hadith is sahih I found a quote saying that al-Albani considered other versions as da'if.

First of all this isn't strictly speaking a hadith as ibn 'Abbas in non of the narrations attributed it to our Messenger. So in best case it is a hadith marfo' or mawquf (with a stopped narrator chain), al-Albani defined the version of an-Nasa'i as mawquf, as the wording is in passive form and not quoting the source of the prohibition and qualified the chain as sahih. Al-Bayhaqi and al-Albani said that these narrations are among the basis of the view of abu Hanifa (quoted only by al-Albani by name) to allow alcohol made of other kind of fruits except grapes and dates. While the majority is following the hadith quoted at the beginning of my post or similar narrations.

The reference Volume 4 p 497 however can also be from the hanafi book like "al-Hidayah sharh bidyat al-Mubtadi الهداية شرح بداية المبتدي" of [al-Marghinani علي بن أبي بكر المرغياني](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burhan_al-Din_al-Marghinani) or other hanafi books or commentaries.

In the hanafi book "[nusb ar-raya fi takhrij ahadith al-hidaya](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=9&ID=510&idfrom=3506&idto=3535&bookid=9&startno=13)" of a Abdullah az-Zayla'i عبد الله الزيلعي , he quoted that the version of this hadith above (as quoted by you: as a saying of Muhammad himself, not as a mawquf of ibn 'Abbas) has according to al-'Oqayli (in his boook ad-Du'afa' = "the weak narrators") has several issues in the narrator chains. Even if there's a hadith of Ali ibn Abi Talib which seems more likely to be close to your quote

> "Khamr was forbidden in and of itself and every kind of intoxicating drink."

qualified as da'if by al-Albani ([Arabic link](http://hdith.com/hdith.php?s=fd22)) 
beside others narration

> "Khamr was forbidden in and of itself and the intoxicating of any other drink."

on the authorithy of abu Sa'id al-Khudri, ibn 'Abbas and Ali qualified as da'if because of unknown and munkar (rejected) narrators ([Arabic link](http://hdith.com/hdith.php?s=fd21)).

...
I stopped searching for a book including the words al-Hidaya in at least 4 Volumes as none of my findings had this hadith in Volume 4 p 407 the closes to that is [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=5bhFCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT426&dq=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D9%85%D8%B1%20%D8%AD%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU_IPvncbPAhVDkCwKHTslCKAQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D9%85%D8%B1%20%D8%AD%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9&f=false) and the book of [al-Marghinani](https://books.google.de/books?id=OPTXAAAAMAAJ&q=%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D9%85%D8%B1%20%D8%A8%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%8C%20%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%83%D8%B1%20%D9%85%D9%86%20%D9%83%D9%84%20%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9&dq=%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D9%85%D8%B1%20%D8%A8%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%8C%20%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%83%D8%B1%20%D9%85%D9%86%20%D9%83%D9%84%20%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgm9ugocbPAhUJhSwKHU8iD6EQ6AEIMjAD) (without commentaries, I only found it with commentaries and their in the 7th Volume!)

**Conclusion**

The version of the hadith used as a reference is considered as da'if and in the most authentic versions it is not presented as a saying of Muhammad, rather than as a hint for a prohibition. It is widely used in hanafi and comparative fiqh books or books quoting or refuting the hanafi view!